# Unable to find web project option in eclipse helios

Tags: eclipse

Can anyone tell me how to get a web project option in eclipse helios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the Java EE version ?

If not download it from here : 
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr2

You can still use your old Helios Java workspace with this the Java EE one.

Comment: If you have any questions comment back. If you get it working according to my answer, please consider accepting it by clicking on the 'Tick' mark next to it like so : http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png.

Comment: Ok i will let u know after installation